# angular2 href attributes crash application

Tags: angular

I have some strange error, if I use href attribute of html inside template angular go crazy and thows 3 exception each second. this occurs "only if I refresh in this page" there is no error if page redirected here via link in another page.. this is another mystery.
[image]
The thing is I made investigation and discovered if I delete "href" attributes from the elements below it looks fixed.

```
<div class="sidebar-box">
            <h3><i class="boxed fa fa-th"></i>Populer Topics</h3>
            <div class="tabs-top">
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-2">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Announcements</a></li>
<!--I wish it worked.. <a [routerLink]="['#tabs-1']">Events</a>-->
                  </ul>
                <div id="tabs-1">
                    <ul class="latest-blog-posts">
                        <li class="cf">
```

but I need to use this href attributes to keep functionality of ui so I tried routerLink instead but cant fix it..
So If I leave it like above recursive zone.js already loaded error occurs, deleting href attriburtes from tab list looks solve problem but I need these links open the related tab when clicked.. How can I achieve this?

index.ts

```
export * from './app.component';
export * from './app.module';
```

main.ts

```
import './polyfills.ts';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppModule } from './app/';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: So you said you tried routerLink. Could you provide how you tried it?

Comment: edited post for you, check the comment line under li items

Comment: In your `routerLink` attempt The brackets `[ ]`  could cause your problem, try removing them `<a routerLink="#tabs-1">Events</a>`

Comment: @AJT_82 no it has same effect as href. directing entire page diffirent url